# add wifi adapter to juniper Olive or vMX

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

Can I add a wifi adapter to a juniper olive or vMX vm so it thinks its a regular Ethernet adapter?

Edit: I would like to do this:

- have a junos Olive/vMX VM running on an esxi host
- connect a wifi adapter to the host and use pass through to the VM
- is there some way for the junos VM to see the wifi adapter as a rotatable interface?

Olive runs on freebsd which would have the drivers for the adapter so at least the underlying OS would see it. Is there a way for the virtual router to see that wifi adapter as an interface?

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense as written. In what way does Juniper Olive think, or should think, it is any sort of ethernet adapter, real or otherwise? Wi-Fi is not ethernet; those are two different protocols.

Comment: This is actually an "ESXi" question rather than a network engineering question. It really doesn't matter whether you run Olive in the VM or Linux or Windows or anything else. The question should be "can I add a wireless network adapter to an ESXi host?" The answer is probably "no, because there are no wifi adapters on the HCL ( http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php )" - but you're better off asking on a different site.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about VM configurations are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fooling a router OS to think that one sort of network is a different sort of network will lead to failure. A router needs to build the frame encapsulation for packets leaving through an interface. An ethernet frame is fundamentally different than a Wi-Fi frame. If you somehow manage to send an ethernet frame through a Wi-Fi adapter, none of the WAPs or Wi-Fi clients will understand it.